# How can I reset a layer transformation to the original state after I did some animations and transformations?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a image that rotates around a few times by random and then disappears. After it appears again, I want it to be in the original state. Not rotated. I would keep track of how many rotations I applied randomly and then calculate how many radians I have to re-do that. But I slightly remember from the big docs that there was some identity transformation thing. Is that what I am looking for? Just want to ask before I spent a whole day in finding it to then know it's not the right thing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want to set the transformation matrix to the identity transform; that will have the effect of "resetting" the transformation.

Answer (score 14):

In code, that will look like:

```
yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```